# jquery validate rules apply even if input is not set as required

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm running in to an issue regarding how rules are applied with jQuery validate.

If a rule for FirstName is declared, jQuery validate will trigger an validation error for that field even if the input does not have the required attribute set.

I'm running validation as a nested function in a jQuery form builder plugin.
The plugin generates a form based on json data received from marketo.
The reason for nesting the validation is so that the validation for several forms across several domains can be managed in one script.

The reason I'm querying how can I prevent rules from triggering it the required attribute is not applied to a form field is because of how marketo outputs the forms and the form names.

Example form:

```
<form action="" id="form" method="post">
  <div class="formrow">
    <label for="FirstName">First name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Example validation:

```
  $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      FirstName: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      FirstName: "Please enter your name"
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        error: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        },
        success: function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    },
    errorElement: "em",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      error.appendTo(element.closest(".formrow").children("label"));
    }
  });
```

I've put together a demo to show the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/onebitrocket/dzv5ugo0/

Answer (score 1):

The `required` attribute is not on the element, but you have defined `required: true` in the `rules` object for `FirstName`, hence why the field is required. Remove the `rules` object for that element and it should work as you require.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/dzv5ugo0/7/)

Comment: Thanks, but that will only work for one form. I need a workaround so I can use a single validation code based shared over different forms, where not all fields will always be required - one option I can think of is to remove the rules completely for all forms, this seems to work well. The other would be to dynamically generate the validation rules and messages based on the json data supplied by marketo. I wonder if that is even possible?